Tokens nightmare
Is there any easy way to:

know what tokens will work without randomly guessing what looks correct
test a token without sending test emails or scheduled jobs


Have you read the docs? There are examples of token output on this page. https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/token/

I always check out the User Guide. I never thought of looking at the Developer Guide. I will definitely explore that. Thanks.

In many places where you can enter tokens, there will be a token drop box like this one on the Print/Merge document screen so you don't have to guess.
Print/Merge is also useful for testing - less hassle than sending a mail etc.


One solution is the BtrTplMsg extension which provides a 'preview' option so you can look at any one of previous 25 receipts and see what it would look like. https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/btrmsgtpl
not sure it is quite what you are after though

Thanks. I will look at that.
